# Use and switch the rails command line from master to stable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I would like to try Rails and the `rails` command line synched on the git `master` branch. At the same time I would like to be able to easily update the rails gems to the latest master and also to switch easily to the stable branch to work on existing projects.

Knowing that I'm using rbenv what would be the easiest and more practical solution? Using gem sets?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, using gemsets is your best option here.

For rbenv, there is the excellent [rbenv-gemset](https://github.com/jf/rbenv-gemset) plugin and the detailed README should give you all the direction you need to get started.

I personally store gems on a per-project base, so one of the first steps I do when I start a new project is to run `echo '.gems' > .rbenv-gemsets`.

This will tell the plugin to store all the project’s gem in a folder called `.gems`, local to the project therefore allowing you to use different Rails versions (`master`, `stable`, etc.) in different projects.